# Active Directory attribute to store user "Grade"

Tags: active-directory

I want to store at the user level the Grade of this user : basically if he is a Collaborator, a Manager, a Directory, a General Director etc... (the notion of user being a manager of others is not enough as I need to distinguish between various grades)

Is there an attribute that I could use for that ? (does not seem to)
Should I create a custom attribute ?

Is there another way ? (I could think of creating a group for all managers, a group for all directors and that would allow me to search is a given user is member of a director group for exemple)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom attributes (modifying the schema) is never something you should consider doing lightly (or at all).

AD contains several extension attributes for custom use cases like this. For users these are:

`extensionAttribute1` to `extensionAttribute15` which are all single value string attributes

`extensionName` which is a multi-value string attribute

`extensionData` which is a multi-value binary attribute

You are free to use these attributes for anything without interferring with normal AD operation.

There are also a multitude of standard attributes that may serve your purpose for example the `Job Title` field under Organization.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Job Title which I prefer to use as a Role Description e.g. Project Manager (rather than a Grade Description), the other option for Grade Titles is [`employeeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-employeetype).

However, the one advantage of Job Title is its prominence in the Outlook Address Book.